# Identifying Excel filepath in SSIS

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm using [this ForEach loop tutorial](https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/dynamic-file-name-for-excel-connection-manager-ssis/) in an attempt to import all my Excel files from a folder to an SQL table via SSIS. I followed the steps exactly but can't get the Excel source block to recognize the variable filename. The error I get shows that the filepath did not work at all:

```
Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager ConnectionManagerName
```

The source file formatting, type, and folder are consistent. Has anyone else had this problem? I suspect I'm missing something between steps 2-4 in the link, but I wouldn't know what it is.

Comment: Step 3.a "We have to set the DelayValidation property to true. This will tell the package loader not to validate the connection or file availability" and Step 6 "Set DelayValidation property of Data Flow task to True" are my likely candidates for the missed step

Comment: @billinkc Before posting my question, I'd already toggled that option several times to no effect.

Comment: Then we are at an impasse. I identified the likely cause of your misstep and you've specified that it's been done to spec. To move forward, I propose you take screenshots of your package. Show your over all control flow, your variables, connection managers and anywhere that you have applied expressions

Comment: @billinkc No need to do that now, I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it! I used a ConnectionString in Step 3b instead of ExcelFileName. For anyone reading this answer, the exact ConnectionString format will vary ([see here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)) but will be something like

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```